# How to retrieve (but not overwrite local copy) of an older file in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I have a local Mercurial repository that is up-to-date. I want to retrieve an earlier version of one of the files without disturbing my local copy of the repository.

Is there a way to do this? (looks like maybe `hg archive` but I'm not sure how to use it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hg cat -r <rev> file_name.foo > new_file_name.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to look at a previous revision of a file would be with `hg update -r <revision number>` to update your working directory to that revision, then to look at the file.  If you really don't want to touch your working directory, clone your repo, then use `hg update` on the clone.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do that, I'd have to clone the whole repository and all I need is just one file.

Comment: hg uses copy-on-write links, so it would actually not take up more space n the harddrive.